# geth and web3js asking password

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am trying to send ethers to another address, using `geth`, and then `geth attach`, and then using `web3js`. But it is asking password:

> Error: authentication needed: password or unlock

But I never put a password on any of the accounts. I tried the `--unlock` option when starting `geth`, but it only says `Attempting to unlock, attempt 1/3` in the debug log, nothing else. I use all options in `--rpcapi` when starting `geth`. So what is this? Which password is it asking?

Comment: are you using a private network? If Yes, at some point you must have created an account. When you create an account, you are prompted to enter a password. And when you try to send a transaction from that address you need to unlock the account. The command used to unlock account is : `personal.unlockAccount("address")`. If still there is an issue, please update your question with more details like what are the exact steps you did to setup your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to create unlocked accounts. It is however possible that you set an empty password (just hit enter when asked for password). If that is the case, you still need to `personal.unlockAccount("address")` and just hit enter when asked for the password.

Answer (score 0):

It is telling could not decrypt Error: could not decrypt key with given passphrase

if I am using personal.unlockAccount("address")

I have created account with empty password